# Update data with latest date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table `tblpushproducts`:

```
identifier  createddate   creator 
1           15-7-2018     Utrecht (Utr)
1           1-12-2018     Utrecht (Utr)
1           14-2-2019     Utrecht (Utr)            
2           12-12-2018    Utrecht (Utr)
2           12-02-2019    Utrecht (Utr)
```

I want to update the value in column `creator` from `Utrecht (Utr)` to `Utrecht`.
But, as you can see, there are multiple rows for same identifier.
I want to update only the rows with latest date.

So, for example, in this case only these rows should be updated:

```
1           14-2-2019     Utrecht (Utr)
2           12-02-2019    Utrecht (Utr)
```

Comment: what column are you using as PK ?

Comment: there another column called ID which primary column

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
UPDATE tblpushproducts P SET P.creator = NewValue WHERE P.identifier = IDValueHere AND createddate = (SELECT MAX(T1.createddate) FROM tblpushproducts T1 WHERE T1.identifier = IDValueHere);
```

Comment: IDValueHere--you mean to say i shoud explicitly mention here the value???.

Comment: but there is almost 1M data in my table and i want update All data with specified condition.

Comment: IDValueHere is the repeat identifier, in the where clause you specified who is the creator and what is the id that you want to modified for example: UPDATE tblpushproducts P SET P.creator = 'Nikola Tesla' WHERE P.identifier = 1 AND createddate = (SELECT MAX(T1.createddate) FROM tblpushproducts T1 WHERE T1.identifier = 1);

Comment: yes that i know but my question  in one single query how can i update whole table..without putting hardcoded value...because i want to update whole table ...and what u suggest will update only 1 specified record in where clause

Comment: So, create a procedure with a while clause and the ID could be dynamic depending all identifiers in your table, this could you help in all cases that you need update information. Well... is an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to find the latest row:

```
with
x as (
  select
    id, 
    row_number() over(order by createddate desc) as rn from tblpushproducts
)
update tblpushproducts
set creator = 'Donald Duck'
where id = (select id from x where rn = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the rply...i will try this and let you know ;)